# Permission denied SQL

Tags: postgresql, terminal, path, permission-denied

I try to create a table using a file created from mackaroo, so I tried to copy add the SQL file in terminal using this command "\i"

```
test=# \i /home/omar/Documents/person.sql
```

but I get

> /home/omar/Documents/person.sql: Permission denied

Even though, I grant all privilege, and set the file to read & write, I tried every single step, remained unsuccessful.

I tried this grant command:

```
grant all 
chmod +r
```

Comment: This is unclear: *i tried grant command, grant all chmod +r*. `GRANT` is a command the database for permission to create database objects. `chmod` is a command on the operating system for file permission. What exactly did you try? How did you try it?

Comment: let me explain, i download a sql file "person.sql' , so i want to insert it to the my database named "test", in the terminal, when, i do this command 
test=# \i /home/omar/Documents/person.sql
it gaves me >> /home/omar/Documents/person.sql: Permission denied,

Comment: That looks like a file permission error. You (or whatever user you are when you are in the shell) do not have permission to read that file. `grant all` is a DB command - not going to affect file permission. `chmod +r` - honestly I'm not sure if that is syntactically correct. Usually you must say what file you are chmod'ing as part of the command. Did you check the file permissions before and after? And are you making sure you are giving the right permissions to the user that needs access (yourself? psql? A group? Another user?)

Comment: thanks for your reply,   to be more clear, i downloaded a random data (sql) from Mockaroo, for practice, when i got this error "permission denied", i gave the right permissions to the user to get access to this file,  , psql owner , but remained unsuccessful, 
anyway, im adding data manually to the terminal until i find a way to sort out this issue

Comment: The psql owner sounds like you mean the owner of the database. But the main thing is, that user may or may not have permissions on the file. How are you logging into the shell/terminal - as what user? After that do you use an `su` command to switch to another user or not? After that, are you running commands in the shell, or are you next logging into to a psql prompt? And then, what file are you working with and what exact command are you using to "read" the file? We need details!